# Evaluating $\int_x^0 f(x,t) dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, gre-exam

I'm working on reviewing one of the problems in the REA GRE math subject test prep book which is to find the derivative of

$$ f(x) = \int_x^0 \frac{\cos(xt)}{t}dt $$

My first thought was to flip the limits of integration, and then to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I'm not sure how that applies when the function being integrated is a function of $x$ and $t$, and not just $t$ alone.

The book gives the solution, but I don't understand what they do in the first step. They say the derivative is equal to:

$$ - \frac{\cos(x^2)}{x} - \int_0^x \frac{t \sin(xt)}{t}dt $$

But I'm not sure how they got there.

Comment: As far as your integral is concerned, $x$ is a constant. So, your integral is of the form
$$
\int_{a}^{b} {\cos(c \, t) \over t} \; dt,
$$
where $a, b, c$ are constant.  Evaluate this one, and then set $a = c = x, \; b = 0$.

Comment: You cannot find the derivative of a function that is not defined. The function $\frac{\cos(xt)}{t}$ has a non-integrable singularity at $t=0$. The exercise makes sense only if $\cos(xt)$ is replaced by $1-\cos(xt)$ or something similar.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck the problem isn't that $f$ is undefined at a single point -- it is undefined for **every** value of $x$

Comment: Following my remark in the comments, I am assuming that $f(x)$ is defined as
$$ f(x)=\int_{x}^{0}\frac{\cos(xt)\color{red}{-1}}{t}\,dt \tag{0}$$
in order to eliminate the non-integrable singularity at $t=0$.

With such assumption, the change of variable $t=xs, \,dt = x\,ds$ leads to
$$ f(x)=\int_{1}^{0}\frac{\cos(x^2 s)-1}{s}\,ds = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-\cos(x^2 s)}{s}\,ds \tag{1}$$
and differentiation under the integral sign gives:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \int_{0}^{1}2x\sin(sx^2)\,ds = \color{red}{\frac{2-2\cos(x^2)}{x}}=\frac{4}{x}\sin^2\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right).\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like product rule.

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(x,t) dt$$

$$ = f(x,x) + \int_0^x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t) dt$$

Explanation: First differentiate with respect to the bounds treating the $f(x,t)$ constant and then differentiate with respect to the $f(x,t)$ treating the bounds constant.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement